# sfc /scannow: What does "Duplicate ownership for directory" mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, dism, sfc

I'm running WIndows 10 version 1709 (OS Build 16299.248). When I run sfc /scannow, it results in:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix
>   some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log
>   windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

CBS.log shows hundreds of lines like the following:

> Error: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory
>   \??\C:\Windows\System32 in component HyperV-SbResources, version
>   10.0.16299.192, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

When I run Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth it results in:

> Image Version: 10.0.16299.248
>   [==========================100.0%==========================] The
>   restore operation completed successfully. The operation completed
>   successfully.

But sfc /scannow still gives the same errors. What do these errors mean and how can I fix them?

Comment: You shouldn’t run SFC on Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you state your reason why we shouldn't run SFC in Windows 10? Microsoft employees recommend us to do an SFC scan whenever we encounter an error with Windows.

Comment: @iTechieGamer - DISM is a better tool, and on Windows 8+, should be used instead. SFC is a legacy tool.Unless you have Hyper-V enabled, the results of SFC, are erroneous.Even if you have Hyper-V enabled, SFC is complaining about the permissions, within the WinSxS directory. DISM reports your image health has no corruption.  Official Microsoft documentation supports my statements, I have not seen a single Microsoft employee, suggest SFC should be used over DISM if you are using Windows 8+. Users tagged as Microsoft, on Microsoft Answers, are not Microsoft employees (just recognized volunteers).

Comment: @Ramhound Do you have any official documentation that supports your claims? https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4026529/windows-10-using-system-file-checker states that in WIndows 10, DISM should be run, followed by SFC.

Comment: @Jon I only have my decades worth of experience and a nearly decade at SU performing research to answer questions

Comment: @Jon - also supports SFC after DISM https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system

Answer (score -1):

So, this is what I did and it worked for me:

1. Open an elevated command prompt (cmd or PowerShell, doesn't matter)
2. Run `sfc /scannow` and let it repair what it can.
3. Mount an original Windows ISO for the operating system you want to repair.
4. Run this command:  `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:WIM:D:Sources\Install.wim:1`

- D: is the drive on which my ISO was mounted

5. Reboot
6. Run `sfc /scannow` again and for me, it was clean.